# Google Games API -- Connection fails immediately, goes through sign-in process, sign-in fails

Tags: android, google-play-games

I'm attempting to get Google Games to work with my application, but I'm having some issues. When I start my app, I call `googleApiClient.connect();` on my `onStart()` method, along with some other code (posted below). Immediately when I start my app I get the log statement that `onConnectionFailed` was called and then the sign in process begins, the green fragment comes up and tells me to select my account. When I select my account, I get the log that is in `onSignInFailed`. I'm really confused what I'm doing wrong here. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Here we go, I tried to only include the relevant bits:

```
public class SelectionScreen extends BaseGameActivity 
      implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
      GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

    private GoogleApiClient googleApiClient;
    private boolean mResolvingConnectionFailure = false;
    private boolean mAutoStartSignInflow = true;
    private boolean mSignInClicked = false;
    private static int RC_SIGN_IN = 9001;
    private boolean mIntentInProgress;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_selection_screen);

        googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this).addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addApi(Games.API).addScope(Games.SCOPE_GAMES).build();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        googleApiClient.connect();
        Log.d("Attempting to connect..", "");
    }

    @Override
        protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        googleApiClient.disconnect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        Log.d("Connection failed! ", ":-(");

        if (!mIntentInProgress && connectionResult.hasResolution()) {
            try {
                mIntentInProgress = true;
                startIntentSenderForResult(connectionResult.getResolution()
                .getIntentSender(), RC_SIGN_IN, null, 0, 0, 0);
            } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                mIntentInProgress = false;
                googleApiClient.connect();
        }
    }

        if (mResolvingConnectionFailure) {
            return;
        }

        if (mSignInClicked || mAutoStartSignInflow) {
                mAutoStartSignInflow = false;
                mSignInClicked = false;
                mResolvingConnectionFailure = true;

                if (!BaseGameUtils.resolveConnectionFailure(this,
                    googleApiClient, connectionResult,
                    RC_SIGN_IN, "Signing in -- other error")) {
                    mResolvingConnectionFailure = false;
                }
        }

        //show sign in button
         ft = fm.beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragmentTwo);
        ft.addToBackStack(null);
        ft.commit();
    }

    @Override
    public void onSignInButtonClicked(View view) {
        googleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onSignInFailed() {
        Log.d("sign in failed", "");
    }

    @Override
    public void onSignInSucceeded() {
        Log.d("sign in succeeded woo", "");
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int responseCode, Intent intent) {
        super.onActivityResult( requestCode, responseCode, intent );
        mHelper.onActivityResult( requestCode, responseCode, intent );
    }
}
```

Is there some way I can get more detail about exactly *what* is causing the sign in error/connection error?

On the google play developer console it says my OAUTO 2.0 is fine, and I got the SHA thing from my keystore fine.. I'm sure I'm doing something retarded with my code, but I'm just not sure what. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

**edit** Here are the metadata things of my manifest. Maybe I did these wrong? It looks correct from their guide.

```
<application>
//not showing all my activity stuff and application data, did I put the meta-data in the wrong place maybe?
<meta-data
     android:name="com.google.android.gms.games.APP_ID"
     //this is a number from my ids.xml file
     android:value="@string/app_id" />
<meta-data
     android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
     //generated by gradle, it finds the correct number (7327000)
     android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
</application>
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally `BaseGameActivity` does all the heavy lifting for you so there's no need to do all the low level connection stuff in your custom Activity.

As stated [here](https://github.com/01org/cordova-google-play-games-services/blob/master/src/android/com/google/example/games/basegameutils/BaseGameActivity.java):

> Subclasses only need to override the `onSignInSucceeded` and `onSignInFailed` abstract methods. To initiate the sign-in flow when the user clicks the sign-in button, subclasses should call  `beginUserInitiatedSignIn`.

Also, are you sure you've set up Google Play Game Services using your local [**debug** keystore](https://developers.google.com/games/services/console/enabling#c_specify_client_id_settings)?

Comment: Yeah I'm pretty sure that my google play game services with my keystore is working fine, but I'm not 100% sure.. It says it's OK on their site. Is there some better way to check it? Thanks for your response!

Comment: Can you post a log when signing on?  Usually there is a message which points to the issue.  Is the user you are selecting added as a tester in your game on the play console?